# Dedekind MacNeille completion. Definition of supremum as $\left(\bigcup M\right)^{ul}$. Counterexample for definition as $\bigcup M$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

I didn't found a mathematical text for Dedekind MacNeille completion
, so I "defined" supremum in the completion the following way:
$$\sup M := \left(\bigcup M\right)^{ul},$$ where M is a family of some subsets of $S_{DM}$, the completion of $(S,<)$. (okay, supremum is always defined, yes, here as term $(\iota x \in S_{DM}: M\leqslant x)$, but then sometimes it is interpreted as proper partial function on the support of the first order model.)

And it works perfectly, indeed a supremum.

But when I tried $\sup M := (\bigcup M)$ as definition, I got stuck in the proof.
So I suspect, that there is a counterexample for such definition.

Could you please either provide such counterexample, or actually prove that the second definition is also good?

Comment: What is $M$? In order for $\bigcup M$ to make sense, $M$ must be a family of sets, say $M=\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$, and $\bigcup M = \bigcup_{i\in I}M_i$.

Comment: @amrsa Yes, it is a family of sets.(added to question)

Comment: It actually makes perfect sense because if $S_{DM}=\{A\subseteq S:A^{ul}=A\}$, and so each element is a set, and if $M\subseteq S_{DM}$, then $M$ is a family of subsets of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the smallest counterexample is the following:
let $S=\{\bot,a,b,c\}$, where $\bot$ is the least element and $\{a,b,c\}$ forms an anti-chain.

Then, $S_{DM}$ just adds a top element.
Following the definition, the elements of $S_{DM}$ are
$$\{\bot\}, \{\bot,a\}, \{\bot,b\},\{\bot,c\},\{\bot,a,b,c\},$$
where $\{\bot,a,b,c\}$ is the top element.

Now let $M=\{ \{\bot,a\}, \{\bot,b\} \}$;
it follows that $\bigcup M =\{\bot,a,b\}$ (which is not a member of $S_{DM}$), but
$$\left(\bigcup M\right)^{ul} = \{\bot,a,b,c\}.$$